# Overriding implementation in a specific type for generics

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I know rust is not a "inheritance/subtyping" language, but I wanted to know if it is possible to override implementations in a specifically typed generic:

```rs
trait Trait {}

enum Enum {}
impl Trait for Enum {}

struct Struct<T: Trait> {}
impl<T> Struct<T> where T: Trait {
    fn function(&self) {
        panic!("Not Implemented!")
    }
}

impl Struct<Enum> {
    fn function(&self) {
        println!("This works")
    }
}

fn main(){}
```

This raises the compiler error

```
error[E0592]: duplicate definitions with name `function`
  --> foo.rs:10:5
   |
10 |     fn function(&self) {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ duplicate definitions for `function`
...
16 |     fn function(&self) {
   |     ------------------ other definition for `function`
```

Any way to go around this?

Comment: You need the unstable [specialization](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1210-impl-specialization.html) to do this.

Comment: I’m not sure specialization would even solve this specific case, as both methods are on inherent implementations.  If they were trait methods, then specialization of that trait is possible as an unstable/nightly feature.

Comment: May I ask what your use case is? Is one method an optimized version of a generic variant, or are the different implementations doing fundamentally different things?

Comment: @MarkusKlein I'd like to have a function that takes a `Struct<T>` and call function, but have it be implemented differently depending on what generic it is using -- and the default behavior, for the unimplemented, should raise an error.

Comment: @MarkusKlein this is because I want to consider the `function` to be a black box: it might produce different answers depending on what concrete type it has, but from a different function that takes in `Struct<T>`, I want it to be generic instead of creating the same copy for each implementation of `T`.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer No, there is (currently) no way in Rust to have specialized implementations. If there would be, IMHO the main use case would be optimization, i.e. doing essentially the same thing in a smarter manner, specific for the type in question.

Slightly longer answer: You may be able to abuse the priority of implementations to achieve something to that effect.

```rust
use std::marker::PhantomData;

enum Enum {}

trait NotImplemented {
    fn function(&self);
}

impl<T> NotImplemented for Struct<T> {
    fn function(&self) {
        panic!("Not Implemented!")
    }
}

struct Struct<T> {
    marker: PhantomData<T>
}

impl Struct<Enum> {
    fn function(&self) {
        println!("This works")
    }
}

fn main(){
    let working = Struct::<Enum> { marker: PhantomData };
    let other = Struct::<()> { marker: PhantomData };

    working.function(); // Prints "This works"
    other.function(); // Prints "Not implemented"
}
```

I know to little about the use case to tell you if this is a bad idea. At the very least it might be surprising to other maintainers, so be careful.