# Derive all convertion operators from generic inner type

Tags: generics, rust, metaprogramming, wrapper

I'm trying to use new-type pattern, but I want it to have only semantic meaning, without forcing representation. So let's say

```rust
struct Amount<T>(T);
```

So later I can use `Amount<i32>` or `Amount<f64>` – both are sematicaly valid, and the inner type will depend only on context. But now I'd like to inherit all conversion operators from the inner type:

```rust
impl<T, U: From<T>> TryFrom<Amount<T>> for Amount<U> {
    type Error = U::Error;

    fn try_from(v: Amount<T>) -> Self {
        v.0.try_into().map(Self)
    }
}
```

It won't compile because of a conflicting implementation with `impl<T, U> TryFrom<U> for T where U: Into<T>;`. How could I bypass this restriction?

Comment: There is no way to bypass the restriction, unfortunately. The only other option is too manually implement for each type you actually want to cover.

Comment: You can do it with a method instead of a trait implementation.

Comment: If you ask is it possible to "automatically" implement for `Amount<T>` all the traits that `T` implementes and forward them to the inner value, the answer is that it is not (and I don't think it could ever be) possible. You have to manually (or using some macros) implement traits you are interested with (which is pretty hard, when you are a library author and want to integrate with the greater rust ecosystem, you will often see such things guarded with feature gates, for example for `serde`, or `num`).

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze I need only limited set of standard traits, of which `From` seems the most prominent and most difficult

Answer (score 0):

You can't bypass the restriction (although there is an [unstable proposal](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1210-impl-specialization.html) for a [specialization implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69156093/overriding-implementation-in-a-specific-type-for-generics), which I'm not sure of whether it would even work in this case). But: you also do not need to bypass it.

You could just implement the `Into<T>` trait for `Amount<T>` and then simply use that in your `TryFrom<U>` implementation for `U : Into<T>`. Then since `Amount<T> : Into<T>` there would be a `TryFrom<Amount<T>>` implementation out of the box.

```rust
impl<T> Into<T> for Amount<T> {
    type Error = U::Error;

    fn into(v: Amount<T>) -> T {
        v.0
    }
}
impl<T, U : Into<T>> TryFrom<U> for Amount<T> {
    type Error = U::Error;

    fn from(v: U) -> Self {
        v.into().map(Self)
    }
}
```